# LOVE2d [ERROR] attempt to index global 'player' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, syntax-error, love2d

So I'm playing around with the Grid-Locked Player Tutorial from the LOVE2d wiki, and I come across this error when I try to run it. "attempt to index global 'player' (a nil value)"

Full Code: [My Code](http://www.codeshare.io/4t7la)

Here's the specific code snippet that was causing the problem.

```
if enemyFOV <= player.grid_x then
    shoot()
end
```

I've already looked at other similar questions on this site, and none seemed to apply to my problem. Except for one that had the solution of using

```
return
```

after the shoot() function.

So Stack Overflow, my question is, What should I do to fix this?

Comment: That error means the global variable `player` is `nil` which means your `love.load` function (since that's where you create it) hasn't run yet (or `player` has been set to `nil` somewhere else.

Comment: Can you identify it at all? Where it might be defined nil? That would be a great help. @EtanReisner

Comment: Nothing in the code you linked to assigns to it other than the `love.load` function so no, I can't. Is that *all* of the code in question? When, while running the code, do you get the error?

Comment: It says it happens in line 64-Along with the Traceback notes in function 'require' and function 'xpcall' @EtanReisner

Comment: Oh! That `if` block isn't in any function. It is at the top-level and is being run while your code is being loaded. I'm assuming that's supposed to be in the `shoot` function?

Answer (score 0):

Etan Reisner had the correct answer here. The code snippet that is giving you the error resides outside of any function. If you move the offending code inside of love.update(), your problem should be solved.